# How to get last outgoing call in Android

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-studio

I'm working with an app that uses Android Intent class to make calls.

I can successfully create a call to a number so that is working.

What I want now is to show the last outgoing call number to show in a TextView.
Also I made that TextView to be clickable so by a click I can redial the number.

I'm using CallLog.Calls.getLastOutgoingCall(getApplicationContext()); to get the last called number.
This works only once in my application.

I start the application, enter a number and it makes a call. The first outgoing called number I set in the TextView. After that I enter a second number which is successfully set in the TextView **but** when I click to redial the app calls the first number!

Why is that?
My last outgoing number is the second.
Why is it calling the first number?

Also if I restart the app then it redials the second outgoing number.

Here is my code:

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

Button btnCall;
TextView number;
EditText calledNumber;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    btnCall = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
    number = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
    calledNumber = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);

    //Gets the last outgoing number from the call log
    final String lastCalledNumber = CallLog.Calls.getLastOutgoingCall(getApplicationContext());

    btnCall.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            String TheNumber = calledNumber.getText().toString();
            Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
            callIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:" + TheNumber));
            startActivity(callIntent);
            number.setText(TheNumber);
        }
    });

    //redial number in TextView by click
    number.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            Intent call = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
            call.setData(Uri.parse("tel:" + lastCalledNumber));
            startActivity(call);
        }
    });
}
```

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per the [activity lifecycle](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html), `onCreate()` is only called once and does not run each time your app appears - this would mean that your `getLastOutgoingCall()` would be correct the first time but wouldn't necessarily work the second time.

If you'd like to run something every time the activity appears, you should move it to `onResume()` - this ensures it will always be up to date:

```
String lastCalledNumber;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     // Same except without the `getLastOutgoingCall()`
}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    lastCalledNumber = CallLog.Calls.getLastOutgoingCall(this);
}
```

Comment: Sorry..not sure i understand what you mean.. :(
Im setting the call number here number.setText(TheNumber);

Comment: Ok! But will onResume always get the last outgoing number when i click on the TextView at same time its sets the last called number also in the TextView?I want to redial the last outgoing number while clicking on the TextView.

Comment: Im getting this error:
 java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resume activity